# How does this line of code work?? - " if (a_set & b_set): print(a_set & b_set) " work

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def common_member(a, b): 

    a_set = set(a) 

    b_set = set(b) 

    if (a_set & b_set): 

        print(a_set & b_set) 

    else: 

        print("No common elements")
```

Comment: Did you consider reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset?

Comment: for if condition:-
```def common_member(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)

    b_set = set(b)

    if a_set & b_set:

        print(a_set & b_set)

    else:

        print("No common elements")


common_member([8, 9, 10, 10,2], [2, 3, 4, 4, 5])```

for else condition:-
```def common_member(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)

    b_set = set(b)

    if a_set & b_set:

        print(a_set & b_set)

    else:

        print("No common elements")


common_member([8, 9, 10, 10], [2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE:  as [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) commented, the `&` operator on sets performs set intersection and returns a new set, that is the intersection of the both. The result set will evaluate to a bool and return True if the intersection is not empty.

In python, many types are compatible with the boolean type. Collections such as lists, tuples and sets are too, and when converted to boolean they return False if and only if they are empty, else they return True.

So in pseudo code, that line says if (a not empty and b not empty) ...

you can test that by `bool(set(a))`

Comment: That is *not* what the expression `(a_set & b_set)` does. the *bitwise* (not boolean) operators do set operations on set-like objects, so `&` is for set intersection, `|` is for set union. So `(a_set & b_set)` returns a new set, the *intersection* of the two sets, and the conditional statement then checks the truthiness of that resulting set (as you stated, whether or not it is empty)

Comment: yeah, my mistake.Will update the answer.